# How to hide elements with in a JComboBox?

Tags: java, vector, jcombobox, jcheckbox, itemlistener

Say I have a JComboBox which contains elements that are in a vector...

```
 public class Shade(){
       //code for creating panels etc and other components/containers
       JCheckBox primary = new JCheckBox("Primary", false);           
       Vector<String> colours = new Vector<String>();
}
public Shade(){
//setTitle, look&feel, defaultCloseOperation, Layouts etc etc...

 colours.add(0, "Purple);
 colours.add(1, "Red");
 colours.add(2, "Blue");
 colours.add(3, "Magenta");

JComboBox<String> colourSelector = new JComboBox<String>(colours);

}
```

If the JCheckBox primary is selected I want to 'hide' the colours purple and magneta from the JComboBox, once the primary JCheckBox has been deselected I would like to reveal the hidden elements, so that the original list pertains.

I tried doing this...

```
   public class eventHandler implements itemListener(){

   Shade refObj;
public eventHandler(Shade rinseFM){
refObj = rinseFM;
}

#Overriding abstract implemented method...
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){

if(refObj.primary.isSelected() == true){
refObj.colours.hide(// index of colours required to hide))
}
}
}
```

The hide method doesn't actually exist, is there anything analogous to this.

Comment: Not sure if such a feature exists with `JComboBox`. You might have to manually remove the items from the model, then add them when you want. Or create your own implementation which allows it. From what I see, this is not supported

Comment: If I remove them, when I deselect the box they will not re-appear. This is a problem, because I would have to say 

          if(refObj.primary.isSelected() == false)
               //add what was removed

which will be a lackluster way of doing what I intend.

Also could you elaborate on creating my own implementation which allows it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
private JFrame frame = new JFrame("JComboExample");
private JCheckBox primary = new JCheckBox("Primary");
private JComboBox<String> colorSelector;

private String[] colorsToHide = { "Purple", "Magenta" };

public JComboExample() {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        setupFrame();
        setupCheckbox();
        initJComboBox("Purple", "Red", "Blue", "Magenta");
        frame.add(primary, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(colorSelector, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    });
}

private void setupFrame() {
    frame.setSize(300, 100);
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
}

private void setupCheckbox() {
    primary.addActionListener(event -> {
        if(primary.isSelected()) {
            for(String color: colorsToHide) {
                colorSelector.removeItem(color);
            }

        } else {
            for(String color: colorsToHide) {
                colorSelector.addItem(color);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void initJComboBox(String... colors) {
    colorSelector = new JComboBox<String>(colors);
}

public void setVisbility(boolean visibility) {
    frame.setVisible(visibility);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JComboExample example = new JComboExample();
    example.setVisbility(true);
}
```

This class implements a callback(adds an ActionListener) when the checkbox is clicked. In the callback, when the checkbox is activated, we simply remove the colors in the array `colorsToHide`. If the checkbox is not activated, we add them back.

**Side notes:**

In Java, you should not be using a vector for this purpose. Vectors are largely considered obsolete. See this post: [Why is Java Vector class considered obsolete or deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated)

You should also create all GUI / handle all GUI state changes on the EDT. Swing is not thread-safe and although in most cases it may appear un-needed, it is good practice to call `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` or `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait` before handling the GUI.

Comment: What is EDT?
What is thread-safe?
What does -> even mean? -_-'

Comment: The EDT is the Event Dispatch Thread, you can read about this here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html. You can read this article on thread saftey: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076747/core-java/design-for-thread-safety.html.

() -> 
Is a lambda expression, you can read about these here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: @RamanSB Don't forget to mark this answer as "accepted answer", if it assisted you, by clicking the checkmark under the voting arrows